# Function will not return array when range contains only one value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function meant to return an array which is created out of a single-column list of data. I have been using this function's return value essentially as a pseudo-global variable (`LINENAMES_ARRAY`) which I pass to many functions. Those functions than do checks on it such as `If Len(Join(LINENAMES_ARRAY)) = 0 Then` or go through items with `For Each` statements. Here is the code:

```
  Function LINENAMES_ARRAY() As Variant
  'returns an array of all items in the main sheet linenames column
      LINENAMES_ARRAY = Application.Transpose(MAIN.Range( _
      MAIN.Cells(MAIN_HEAD_COUNT + 1, MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN), _
      MAIN.Cells(LINENAMES_COUNT + 1, MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN)))
  End Function
```

I recently stumbled on one of those you-don't-see-it-till-you-see-it problems while using this workbook for a new project, where if the array happens to be only 1 element, everything fails. Apparently in that case, this returns a single value so `Join()` will fail `For Each __ in LINENAMES_ARRAY` will too. Why won't it treat this as a 1x1 array rather than a free value? I have started to mitigate the problem by rewriting functions where this is called, to check whether it is an array, then do some other procedure. Things like:

```
For j = 1 To LINENAMES_COUNT
    LINES_BOX.AddItem lineNames(j)
Next j
```

is changed to:

```
If Not IsArray(LINENAMES_ARRAY) Then
     myListBox.AddItem CStr(LINENAMES_ARRAY)
Else
    For j = 1 To LINENAMES_COUNT
       LINES_BOX.AddItem LINENAMES_ARRAY(j)
    Next j
End If
```

However this becomes messy and is adding many extra checks to my code that I would prefer to handle in the `LINENAMES_ARRAY` function. Is there a way to return a 1x1 array? Or any other workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array can have a single element if you create it as a single element array and populate it in an array manner.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MAIN_HEAD_COUNT As Long
Dim LINENAMES_COUNT As Long
Dim MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN As Long
Dim MAIN As Worksheet

Sub stuff()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Set MAIN = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN = 2
    MAIN_HEAD_COUNT = 2
    LINENAMES_COUNT = 2

    arr = LINENAMES_ARRAY()
    Debug.Print IsArray(arr)
    Debug.Print LBound(arr) & ":" & UBound(arr)
End Sub

Function LINENAMES_ARRAY() As Variant
    Dim a As Long, tmp() As Variant
    ReDim tmp(0 To LINENAMES_COUNT - MAIN_HEAD_COUNT)
    For a = 0 To LINENAMES_COUNT - MAIN_HEAD_COUNT
        tmp(a) = MAIN.Range(MAIN.Cells(MAIN_HEAD_COUNT + 1, MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN), _
                            MAIN.Cells(LINENAMES_COUNT + 1, MAIN_LINENAMES_COLUMN)).Cells(a).Value2
    Next a
    'returns an array of all items in the main sheet linenames column
    LINENAMES_ARRAY = tmp
End Function
```

Results from the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx):

```
True
0:0
```

Comment: Jeeped nailed it. You are only creating a Variant, then letting VBA decide what the datatype really is (thus Variant). VBA is deciding that a value of only one element is NOT an array and is likely casting it as a String. If you specifically create an array, then set the function return value to that array, it will be an array even if it only has one element.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Also is this not possible without a loop? I would prefer to just assign a full range instead, unless the difference in speed is minimal.

Comment: @teepee - The function could be rewritten to bulk load values if there were more than one but it would also have to create the single element array as a 1 to 1, not a 0 to 0. Loading an array from more than a single cell on the worksheet always creates a 2-D array, even if the second rank is only 1 to 1. e.g. var = Range(B2:B5) is 1 to 4, 1 to 1. var = Range(C3:F3) is 1 to 1, 1 to 4. Currently the array being constructed is zero-based and one dimensioned. You don't have to transpose it. If there were several thousand entries, it would be worth it but I don't believe that is the case here.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks that's good to know. I suppose I find it hard to strike a balance between trying to make compact functions and make robust functions. I tend to err on the side of the former, but always like when I can find a more elegant solution, even when I sacrifice reliability, so I need to be more careful,